# cout output with visual studio and C++/OpenGL

Tags: c++, visual-studio, glut

If I have a main function like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize (800, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow ("A");

    init();
    glutIdleFunc(update);
    glutDisplayFunc(draw);
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutSpecialFunc(specialKeyboard);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);

    cout<<x<<" "<<"Printed out variable x"<<endl;
    cout<<y<<" "<<"Printed out variable y"<<endl;
    cout<<z<<" "<<"Printed out variable z"<<endl;
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Where can I see the result of the cout calls?

Comment: I guess you did not to set the subsystem linker flag to CONSOLE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're working in a Console Application Project, then the output should appear on the console (the command prompt-like window that opens with the OpenGL window).

If you are not working in a Console Application, and you have a Win32 or Empty project instead, then you will have to set the subsystem linker flag to CONSOLE, as mkaes pointed out in his comment.  To do so (in Visual Studio 2010):

- Right click on your Project in the Solution Explorer.
- Click 'Properties' at the bottom of the list that pops up.
- In the navigation list on the left, expand 'Linker' and click on 'System'.
- The first variable in the list should be labeled 'SubSystem'.
- Click on the dropdown for this variable, and select 'Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)'
- Apply the settings and run your project again.